# Is the closed ball of a normed space closed in any Hausdorff locally convex topology, weaker than the norm topology?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, duality, topological-vector-spaces

Assume that we have a normed space $X$ and a subspace $Y$ of $X^{*}$ such that $Y^{\perp}=\{0\}$. They form a non-degenerate dual pare.

Moreover, $\|y\|=\sup_{x\in B_{X}}|\langle x,y\rangle|$, where $B_{X}$ is the closed unit ball of $X$.

I want to prove the symmetric equality, or equivalently, that $B_{Y}^{0}=B_{X}$. Since $B_{X}^{0}=B_{Y}$, this means that $B_{X}=B_{X}^{00}$. So, by the theorem about bipolar, we are left with the question whether $B_{X}$ is closed int the $\sigma(X,Y)$ topology. The latter is in fact a generic Hausdorff locally convex topology weaker than the initial one.

Obviously, this is true when $Y$ is a predual of $X$, which generates one of the minimal such topologies. However my intuition tells me that this should be wrong in general, but I cannot come up with a counterexample.

Thank you.

Comment: Since this has still not evinced a response, let me say that the condition of your third line ensures that the ball is closed in  the $\sigma(X,Y)$ topology.  For a situation where this is not so, consider the Banach space of bounded, holomorphic functions on the unit disc and let $Y$ be the linear span of the point evaluations on the disc with radius $\frac 12$.  This violates both conditions.

Comment: couperin answered your question, but if you want to explore further, Google total nonnorming subspaces.

Comment: That is true if $X$ is complete. However, as written, the completeness of $X$ seems to be nowhere assumed. Then the answer is "No".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying but if you are implying that my comment is flawed, then I beg to differ.